# How to ensure your logic puzzle has no loopholes?

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking, puzzle-creation

Alright, say you've made this logic based puzzle, but when you post it, people find tons of **loop holes**, that obviously wasn't what you want! You didn't tag it with [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) or [brainteaser](/questions/tagged/brainteaser)!

It's times like these where you want to undo the ask button, because *it's just a matter of time before people **DV** and **VTC** "Too Broad"*

So what are some **general** *tips/advice* to **avoiding** such situations where you just want to rip your hair out? *How can you perfect the logic puzzle so people can't come in and ruin the fun, during the last phase of puzzle creation?*

Comment: I think this question should go on meta.

Comment: @Bob This isn't about the site, it's about creating puzzles...

Comment: The description of the SE is "For those who study the *creation* and solving of puzzles."

Comment: I think the problem is that it really depends on the puzzle. I can't think of a way to answer this *in general* (beside getting some extra eyes on it before posting).

Comment: Why the hell is this getting DV? "Is your question about creation and solving of puzzles?" Well it most certainly is!

Comment: Post your puzzle on puzzling.se and refine them ;)

Comment: @McKevin You do have a point. This is one of the few SE communities that are still somewhat friendly.

Comment: @McKevin: Exactly my point (and now also my 'answer'.)

Comment: I do like the direction of this question, but I feel like you could get better answers if you narrow down to a type of question. Also, there's no need to bring up downvotes and votes to close.

Comment: Is this about your "writing numbers" question?

Comment: Is it not generally understood behavior here to add a comment to improve a question, rather than DV/VTC? (as long as a question's improvable/repairable, that is)

Comment: Two approaches I've sometimes used are to postulate that the entities with which one is interacting treat rudeness as punishable by death, or specify that if someone who is asked a ambiguous or paradoxical question may give any answer which is not unambiguously less appropriate than some alternative answer.  Someone judging solutions should not seek loopholes to claim straightforward questions are ambiguous, but should not be averse to assuming that ambiguous questions may be answered in the most vexatious way possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Puzzles in general

It is often close to *impossible* to make a brainteaser-logic puzzle *bullet-proof* without ruining it. A certain *amount* of loop-holes is, what keeps the puzzles interesting after all.

The real question then is, how to *deal* with loop-holes and brain-teaser puzzles as a puzzle author. I would recommend the following guidelines:

> **State that you do not seek for some extra-clever loop-hole answer**, but for an answer within the framework of the puzzle.

Depending on the type of puzzle, this is more or less difficult, but such a statement

1. Indicates you're *serious* about this puzzle.
2. Gives you a handhold against wild-guesses.

> **Change your viewpoint**. Try to *solve* your puzzle with loop-holes. If one is found, decided if it is a 'reasonable' or a very 'obscure' one, and safe-guard accordingly.

If there are loopholes just because some statements *can be misinterpreted* or are *missing*, then fix the text accordingly.

**Example:** A recent example is [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8127/finding-doctor-no). It omits an important statement, that questions are *truthfully* answered, and it does not clearly define what is meant by *being known*. This opens up to loop-hole answers, and could very easily be avoided.

**Counter-Example:** In [the same puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8127/finding-doctor-no), one could creatively construct a rather obscure loop-hole that Dr. No is the person watching the party from the security cameras only. This is clearly *outside* the original puzzle-scope and it is not worthwhile to safeguard against such answers. (Except by the general statement.)

> **Double or Triple-check *your* logic.** Is it really 'tight' ?

It can be helpful to ask the puzzle to another person with and without giving your intended answer. A second opinion can be very helpful.

---

---

## Puzzles on PuzzlingSE

The three points above are generally helpful, but on the other hand, PuzzlingSE is (also) *about* learning if your puzzle works or not. So maybe the real question is less on *how to avoid* the situation than on *how to deal with it.*

> **React *positively* on comments and loop-hole answers.**

Somebody spotted a weak point in your puzzle - that's great news! It allow making it better *by fixing it*! Take the comment/solution seriously. If it is just a *joke* or very *obscure* - tell the poster and otherwise ignore. If it is, however, justifiable, then follow the next advise:

> **Edit your question to improve.**

Whenever you think that you've spotted a better way to present your puzzle - make that edit! PuzzlingSE is *not* 'fun for the moment', but it's ultimate goal is to be useful (and searchable) for future readers. Even if you've already got an accepted answer, if you find a way to make your original post better then **do it**.
If this edit changes the puzzle drastically or makes some of the existing answers look strange, make the edit *visible* as an edit and/or add an according comment to the existing answers.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll wait for other answers before accepting though.

Comment: I found this answer really useful, it would be great to have something like this in the help section for the site.